# Change display property onfocus/onblur

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, onfocus

I've looked up a few other questions on the site, but am still at a loss. I wanted to use Javascript (no JQuery) to take the form below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        <title>Account Sign-Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Profile Sign-Up</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <p><label for = "first_name">First Name: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "first_name" onfocus = "javascript:showText(1)"/>
                 <div id = "div1" style = "display:none">Enter your first name</div>
                 
                <p><label for = "last_name">Last Name: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "last_name" onfocus = "showText(2)"/>
                 <div id = "div2" style = "display:none">Enter your last name</div>
                 
                <p><label for = "email">E-Mail: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "email" onfocus = "showText(3)"/>
                 <div id = "div3" style = "display:none">Enter E-Mail</div>
                 
                <p><label for = "username">Username: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "username" onfocus = "showText(4)"/>
                 <div id = "div4" style = "display:none">Enter your desired screen name</div>
                 
                <p><label for = "password">Password: </label>
                 <input type = "password" id = "password" onfocus = "showText(5)"/>
                 <div id = "div5" style = "display:none">Enter the password you will use to log into your account in the future</div>
                 
                <p><label for = "retype_password">Retype your password again: </label>
                 <input type = "password" id = "retype_password" onfocus = "showText(6)"/>
                 <div id = "div6" style = "display:none">Type your password again</div>
                 
                <p><button name = "submit" type = "button" id = "submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <script src = "Q10.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and apply the following script to display some hidden text whenever the text boxes gain focus. I don't wish to go beyond the scope of what is described. So no, I can't use pop-up tooltips or text in a single div element in a footer, etc. I'm also unconcerned with data injections or the vulnerability/security of the code, as I am not using it for anything practical.

```
var enableBtn = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
};
//function enables submit button

var disableBtn = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
};
//disables submit button

var checkInput = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("password").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("username").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("password").value === document.getElementById("retype_password").value) {
        enableBtn();
    }
    else {
        disableBtn();
    }
};

var showText = function (numb) {
    document.getElementById("div" + numb).style = "display:inline";
};
var hideText = function(numb) {
    document.getElementById("div" + numb).style = "display:none";
};

document.onfocus = checkInput
//if password and username have an input- and retype password is the same as password, button is usable. If not, it's disabled. 

document.getElementById("retype_password").oninput = checkInput;
document.getElementById("password").oninput = checkInput


//document.getElementById("password").onclick = function() {alert(document.getElementById("password").value.length)};
//
```

I'm currently running into a hiccup because I can't get the events to run scripts on focus, and don't know where else to turn. Please help ><

Comment: Seems `showText()` function gets called properly on `onfocus`. Can not see `hideText()` function gets called? Whats the issue?

Comment: I did it differently in the first html onfocus call from the second. I suppose the first is the right one? But also- I never got anything to display properly- so I never bothered to try getting hiding to work

Comment: Are you running this code on fiddle or any other online editor?

Comment: I'm running it on WebStorm now, and getting that showText isn't defined...nut  I know that if I move my script declaration, the submit button scripts won't work

Comment: Wait- I'll grab the idiot ball. I used the same scripts for something else and forgot to change Q10 to Q14 :l. It does indeed work, but I'm still trying to figure out how to implement hideText

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the way you want it, check the snippet. If not i will close down this answer. what i did is to add/change some code in `showText()`. and i think it would be better to show those divs you used on hiding texts to span(or `<p>`)tag as well. i added css for hiding texts class named `description`. you can remove other codes that you made which is not useful.

```js
var enableBtn = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
};
//function enables submit button

var disableBtn = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
};
//disables submit button

var checkInput = function () {
 
    if (document.getElementById("password").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("username").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("password").value === document.getElementById("retype_password").value) {
        enableBtn();
    }
    else {
        disableBtn();
    }
};

var showText =  function(numb) {
 var desc = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
 for (var i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
  desc[i].style.display ="none";
    }
    document.getElementById("div" + numb).style.display = "inline";
};
var hideText = function(numb) {
    document.getElementById("div" + numb).style = "display:none";
};

document.onfocus = checkInput
//if password and username have an input- and retype password is the same as password, button is usable. If not, it's disabled. 

document.getElementById("retype_password").oninput = checkInput;
document.getElementById("password").oninput = checkInput


//document.getElementById("password").onclick = function() {alert(document.getElementById("password").value.length)};
```

```css
.description:before {
 content: '*';
}
.description {
 display: none;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Profile Sign-Up</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <p><label for = "first_name">First Name: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "first_name" onfocus = "javascript:showText(1)"/>
                 <span id="div1" class="description">Enter your first name</span>

                <p><label for = "last_name">Last Name: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "last_name" onfocus = "showText(2)"/>
                 <span id="div2" class="description">Enter your last name</span>

                <p><label for = "email">E-Mail: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "email" onfocus = "showText(3)"/>
                 <span id="div3" class="description">Enter E-Mail</span>

                <p><label for = "username">Username: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "username" onfocus = "showText(4)"/>
                 <span id="div4" class="description">Enter your desired screen name</span>

                <p><label for = "password">Password: </label>
                 <input type = "password" id = "password" onfocus = "showText(5)"/>
                 <span id="div5" class="description">Enter the password you will use to log into your account in the future</span>

                <p><label for = "retype_password">Retype your password again: </label>
                 <input type = "password" id = "retype_password" onfocus = "showText(6)"/>
                 <span id="div6" class="description">Type your password again</span>

                <p><button name = "submit" type = "button" id = "submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- <script src = "Q10.js"></script> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine but there could be possible Problems:

1.If you are running this on JSFiddle then you can try. `window.showText`. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/5/

```
    window.showText = function (numb) {
    document.getElementById("div" + numb).style = "display:inline";
    };
```

2.Possible cause of [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). I have declared function variable at the top and removed `var`. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/6/

3.Declare your script in `head` before `function` call

Comment: Wait- I'll grab the idiot ball. I used the same scripts for something else and forgot to change Q10 to Q14 :l. It does indeed work, but I'm still trying to figure out how to implement hideText- probably just by using onblur there.... Thank you anyway